# How to auto adjust WebBrowser control height in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7

I have created  a WebBrowser control in the xaml, 
and bind some html via string to it. It's working fine .
But the WebBrowser will never auto adjust its height.

```
<phone:WebBrowser
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="myWebView" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" />

private void WebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String htmlTags = "<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width='480', initial-scale='1'\"></head><body><center>{0}</center></body></html>";
    myWebView.NavigateToString(String.Format(htmlTags, getHTMLContent());
}

public string getHTMLContent()
{
    StringBuilder htmlBody = new StringBuilder();
    htmlBody.Append("<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"704\" height=\"484\" background=\"https://known.com/img/back/123456.jpg\" style=\"background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;\">");
    htmlBody.Append("<tr>");
    htmlBody.Append("<td valign=top>");
    htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute;\">");
    htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute; display: table; width: 132px; height: 132px; top: 44px; left: 44px; z-index:0;\">");
    htmlBody.Append("<img src=\"https://known.com/img/icon/87654.jpg\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/>");
    htmlBody.Append("</div>");
    htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute; display: table; width: 704px; height: 484px; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index:0; \">");
    htmlBody.Append("<img src=\"https://known.com/img/icon/234255.jpg\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/>");
    htmlBody.Append("</div>");
    htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute; display: table; width: 440px; height: 264px; top: 184px; left: 184px; z-index:0;  font-family:times;  font-size:14px;  color:#FFFFFF; \" align=\"center\">");
    htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;\">");
    htmlBody.Append("</div>");
    htmlBody.Append("</div>");
    htmlBody.Append("</div>");
    htmlBody.Append("</td>");
    htmlBody.Append("</tr>");
    htmlBody.Append("</table>");
    return htmlBody.ToString();
}
```

What I want the WebBrowser to be

1) Auto adjust its height depends on the HTML String. If i pass only one image mean, it should auto adjust depends on the image. 
It there is no content mean, browser should hide itself.

2) Should not  scrollable, because the WebBrowser already stretch its height to fit the content.

How can I make it? Please let me any idea to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use javascript to get the height of the rendered html and set it to your WebBrowser control.

Here is an implementation of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/150897/Dynamically-resize-WebBrowser-control-in-Silverlig).

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the link.. It's working fine.. It will suite for me. But I face one more problem. That is, the web page is exceed from the browser. But when I double click the page, the web page is getting fit to the screen. Please let me know any idea for this.

Comment: @vijay upload a sample project somewhere and post the link i will try to sort out.

Comment: Hi @Pradeep.. [Here you can download the sample of my project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9CBE7976CDD57B70!209&authkey=!AB-OiBfrDGf14UU&ithint=file%2czip).. Please download  it and let me any way to resolve my problem.

Comment: Yes, i will look into that