# How to use the web browser in listbox in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7, listbox

I want to add the web browser into the list box.

My requirement is I want to show the HTML contents(,,,etc) in the web browser.

I have try like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
     <phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="myWebView" utility:WebBrowserUtility.Html="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=DataContext.webImage}"/>
      <TextBlock Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="testText" Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=DataContext.webImage}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here web browser doesn't show any thing. If I place this web browser out side of the list box it showing the HTML contents.

Please let me any idea to add the web browser into the list box. I know this is not a good idea. But I don't have another choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put the `WebBrowser` inside a `StackPanel` and you don't set the `Height` of your `WebBrowser`, the `WebBrowser` will get 1 or even 0 pixels as height so it is appearently invisible.

In your case you must set the `Height`, but when you have a Horizontally oriented `Stackpanel` you must consider setting `Width` also.

`Stackpanel` will try to get the less `Height` possible while the `Grid` will try to get the most `Height` possible.

Comment: Thanks.. Now it's working. I face one more problem. That is, the web page is exceed from the browser. But when I double click the page, the web page is getting fit to the screen. Please let me know any idea for this. [This is my Question asked in StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124409/how-to-auto-adjust-webbrowser-control-height-in-windows-phone-7/28145651#28145651)

Comment: [My question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185198/how-to-fit-the-html-content-to-the-web-browser-in-windows-phone-7).. Please Review this also..